# Index bloat on GIN index for INSERT only table

Tags: postgresql, performance, heroku, indexing

I have a table with a column that is an array hstore. In JSON notation, the data for this field looks like:

```
[
  { type: "Pickup", id: "49593034" },
  { type: "User", id: "5903" },
  ...
]
```

The number of hstore's in the array for a single record might be as high as 10,000 although it may be less. This table only receives inserts. No data is removed or updated once a record has been added.

There is currently about 90K records in this table and it will generally grow by a few hundred each day. The values in later records will likely have different IDs than the values in earlier records.

I need to be able to do searches on this column. For example I might want to know all records where this column includes `'type=>User,id=>5903'::hstore`. I found if I created a GIN index on this column and queried with the `&&` operator it is able to search this data very quick.

I had a problem where the bloat on this query had gotten very high. PG stopped using the index and switched to a table scan causing it to be very slow. I fixed this by running `REINDEX` on the index.

I'm finding the bloat comes back after a bit. While it hasn't switched to table scans again (even with a high bloat) I worry it will so have preemptively been reindexing when I see it get high again. Whenever I do this I have to take a function off-line as reindexing blocks usage of that index according to the documentation.

I am using Heroku's PG service and they provide a tool to query for bloat. The query it executes can be found [here](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-pg-extras/blob/master/commands/bloat.js).

After doing the `REINDEX` the index size is about 1GB. When it bloats it grows to about 11GB according to Heroku's query.

My questions are:

1. What exactly is causing the bloat? I understand with tables that a `DELETE` or `UPDATE` will cause bloat. Is the addition of data causing it to have to rebalance a tree or something leading to dead pages in the index or something?
2. Is the data from Heroku's query accurate. I've read some things about some bloat queries being for btrees and not gin indexes. Perhaps it's pointing to a non-existant problem. The only time it actually stopped using the index was when I first did a mass insert to populate the table. After that it has bloated but kept using the index. Maybe I know longer have an issue and am just pre-emptively reindexing for no reason.
3. Is there something I should change in my schema to make this maintenance free?

I was thinking of refactoring this so that the data in this column is stored in a separate table. This separate table would store the type, id and the ID of my main table as separate columns. I would create an btree index on the `type` and `id` field. Would this give me a generally maintenance free lookup? I'm thinking it would also be faster since the `id` could be stored as a true number. Currently it is stored as a string since hstore values are always strings.

Comment: Any bloat estimate that does not use `pgstattuple` is guesswork. Check if the index size is reduced considerably after a `REINDEX`.

Comment: && operator? Did you mean @> ?

Comment: That operator can be used but it won't use the index. I found I had to do `fld && ARRAY['type=>User,id=>5903'::hstore]` to get good performance.